# Efficient query to get n-depth descendants of a node with materialized path pattern in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, tree, aggregation-framework, materialized-path-pattern

Let's say we have a tree structure like:

- node 0

  - node 0.0
  - node 0.1

    - node 0.1.0
    - node 0.1.1

      - node 0.1.1.0
      - ...

Each node stores it's path like `0.1.1.0` where digit is an `id` field(it can be mongodb ObjectId for example) and `.` is a separator(it can be `#` for example).

Let's say I want to get all descendants of some node, then I can use regex like:

`^{node.path}{separator}`(Mongodb: `{ $match: { path: { $regex: '^' + node.path + '#' } } }`

Now let's say I want to get not all but only n-depth descendants, like:

- only immediate children, depth `1`
- only immediate children and their immediate children, depth `2`
- ..., depth `n`

Question is how to do this query as efficient as possible, practically with Mongodb.

Current approach I found working is to do second `$match`(I even somehow cant combine it into one `$match` stage currently) after all descendants `$match`:

```
const baseRegex = { $regex: '^' + node.path + '#' }

aggregation pipeline code...

{ $match: { path: baseRegex} },
{ $match: { path: { $not: { $regex: baseRegex.$regex + '([^#]*#){${depth}}[^#]*$' } } } }

aggregation pipeline code...
```

Can you please help me to find better approach, ideally with just one simple regex in one `$match` stage?

Comment: I would say a more suitable approach for mongodb is to store individual nodes as single documents and use [$graphLookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) to build the tree when needed. For problems related to depth, you can leverage the `maxDepth` clause in `$graphLookup`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a really nice solution, but it needs an introduction of new field.

As materialized path pattern already assumes `path` field maintance burden, we can safely add new `level` field and sync it alongside `path` like `level = path ? path.split(separator).length : 0`.

Level field just knows how deep node is inside the tree, root node will have level 0, it's direct children level 1 and so on.

Now task to get n-depth descendants becomes trivial and can utilize exact index match in Mongodb with implementation like:

```
nodeSchema.index({ level: 1, path: 1 })
...
const baseRegex = { $regex: '^' + node.path + '#' }
{ $match: { path: baseRegex, level: { $lte: node.level + depth } } }
```

I think `level` field can be useful in some sort scenarios too.

**PS** First I set index to `{ path: 1, level: 1 }` and discovered that somehow it is not used by Mongodb but `{ level: 1, path: 1 }` works like a charm.